# How to set font style for entire application in ExtJS 4?

Tags: fonts, extjs4

I would like to know how to set certain font style (size, font name, etc) for an entire application of ExtJS 4?

I hope there is some single setting which can work for entire application.

Please enlighten !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS code below in your custom CSS file:

```
.x-body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}
```

Your custom CSS file comes after **ext-all.css** file like this:

```
<link href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Of course you can use `<style>` tag instead.

**Edit:** (for the comment)

For **Panel Titles** use this:

```
.x-panel-header-text-default,
.x-panel-header-text-default-framed {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}
```

For **Charts** it's different. Because they use Theme for styling. So you can create a theme and use it for charts. To create theme you can do something like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.MyTheme', {
    extend:'Ext.chart.theme.Base',

    constructor: function() {
        Ext.chart.theme.MyTheme.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
            axisLabelBottom: {
                 fill: '#333',
                 font: 'Tahoma 11px'
            },
            axisLabelLeft: {
                 fill: '#333',
                 font: 'Tahoma 11px'
            },
            // other configs
        });
    }
});
```

To see all available configs, check the link below and find **Theming** title:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/drawing-and-charting/

To use **'MyTheme'** for your charts, you can do this:

```
{
    // ...
    xtype: 'chart',
    theme: 'MyTheme',
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to use your solution. It works but its setting font size for some controls like combobox but not working for charts and panel titles. Is there any other rule to set font style for charts, panel titles?

Comment: You're welcome. I've changed the answer according to your request.

Comment: Occasionally, the body element is not generated with .x-body class. In this case you can use: `body, .x-body {...}`

Comment: But the above css doesn't change all the fonts (grid rows, panel title,fields and so on...)...is there any solution?

Comment: @Mahmoud jan: Find any selector you want in the "ext-all.css" file that has the attribute "font-family" (or it's parent). For instance, if you search for 'grid', you can find '.x-grid-row'. After that you can override it the way you want.

Comment: @Natasha  jan!: This doesn't make a good CSS specially if you change the font-size, all the components draw themselves in a wrong way(because ExtJs works in pixel system). The correct solution is using ExtJs Themeing tool which can be accessed here : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/theming